# Paramiko SFTP problems when no password is used

Tags: python, paramiko

I need to upload some files using SFTP, this works from the command line:

```
$sftp myuser@my_remote_host
Connected to my_remote_host
sftp>
```

This is my Paramiko script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import paramiko
import sys
import os

host = "my_remote_host"
port = 22

transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))

username = "myuser"      

LOCAL_PATH = "/tmp/"
REMOTE_PATH = "/dcs/tmp/"
FILE = "myfile"

transport.connect(username = username)

sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
path = LOCAL_PATH + FILE
sftp.put(LOCAL_PATH + FILE, REMOTE_PATH + FILE)

sftp.close()
transport.close()
print 'Upload done.'
```

When executing I get this error:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "paramiko.transport"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./my_sftp.py", line 19, in ?
    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 102, in from_transport
    chan = t.open_session()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 655, in open_session
    return self.open_channel('session')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 745, in open_channel
    raise e
EOFError
```

When adding a private key I get this error:

```
path = os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], '.ssh', 'id_dsa')
key = paramiko.DSSKey.from_private_key_file(path)
transport.connect(username = username, pkey=key)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./my_sftp.py", line 24, in ?
    transport.connect(username = username, pkey=key)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1007, in connect
    self.auth_publickey(username, pkey)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1234, in auth_publickey
    return self.auth_handler.wait_for_response(my_event)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/paramiko/auth_handler.py", line 174, in wait_for_response
    raise e
paramiko.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.
```

Comment: Does your private key require a password to unlock? (ssh-agent or seashell often handle this, but not for paramiko)

Comment: @gfxmonk - paramiko can use an agent as well

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, you can't authenticate with only a username, so the session can't be started.

I can't tell why your privatekey example isn't working without some more information. Is it possible that its the incorrect key for that server? SSH on the command line may be trying multiple keys, or getting it from an agent.

Anyway, it easier to start off with the `SSHClient` class. It will wrap up all the authentication, and host verification pieces in one package. It also has an `open_sftp()` convenience method to return an `SFTPClient` instance.